# How to query for attachments for a specific project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphism

I have a `Project` model, which has many `posts` and `tasks`. Both `posts` and `tasks` have many `attachments`. Attachment is polymorphic. How can I query all the attachments for a single project?

Obviously this doesn't work because we don't have an `attachable` table; we have `posts` and `tasks`. It also produces a `can't eager load polymorphic association 'attachable'`.

```
# project.rb
def attachments
  Attachment.joins(:attachable).where('attachable.project_id = ?', id)
end
```

Rest of code:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :tasks
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :attachments, as: :attachable
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :attachments, as: :attachable
end

class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment: Your title is misleading. Are you simply looking to query attachments for a given project or are you trying to eager load attachments when project is queried?

Comment: I want to query for all attachments for a specific project...

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964678/habtm-polymorphic-relationship