# Rails polymorphic associations and database queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

I've a problem with a couple of polymorphic associations. I'm trying to connect both Users and Recipes to shared Dietary Requirements (DRs) through polymorphic associations, with the dietary requirements available to many-to-many of each.

I've created a Dietary Requirement to test this (Vegetarian), though am having trouble accessing this in the page view. I think the reason for this is that the DR created has the `classifiable_type` `Recipe`, meaning when the database query runs, I can't access this particular instance for my Users as SQLite automatically looks for a `classifiable_type` of `User`. Also, as it stands, each DR appears to have to belong to a specific `User` or `Recipe`, while I'd like them all available to many (or am I wrong here?)

In the console, I can see both `User.first.dietary_requirements` and `Recipe.first.dietary_requirements`, though in the view I can't access these, because of the reasons above.

Is there a way to circumvent this problem and get my view showing a list of User DRs and Recipe DRs, or will I have to adjust my models to achieve this? Right now I'm planning to switch to more verbose has-many-through relationships, with separate join tables between User - DRs and Recipe - DRs. If there's an alternative, Rails-way to achieve this, it'd be great to hear.

Model code below:

Recipe

```
has_many :dietary_requirements, as: :classifiable
```

User

```
has_many :dietary_requirements, as: :classifiable
```

Dietary Requirement

```
belongs_to :classifiable, polymorphic: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need Dietary Requirement to have has_and_belongs_to_many relationship with Users and Recipes, however you cannot have polymorphic HABTM associations. You will need to create a join model for it to work.

More: [HABTM Polymorphic Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964678/habtm-polymorphic-relationship)

Comment: Great, thanks for the advice - good to see I'm not adjusting everything when a simple fix exists. @dgilperez, thanks for the edit, bit tired so missed the code elements :/